# I want to slides images automatically using Carousel in react.js but it's not showing picture in card media

Tags: reactjs

I am using react js and material ui i want to slides images (autoplay) in card media i don't know what i am doing wrong please let me know if anyone got to know.

```
<CardMedia
        component="img"
        height="194"
        image={ 
          <Carousel autoplay>
            {product.images.map((image, index) => (
              <div key={index}>
                {console.log(image)}
                <img
                  src={`http://localhost:5000/${image}`}
                />
              </div>
            ))}
          </Carousel>
        }
      />
```

import by using this

```
import { Carousel } from 'react-responsive-carousel';
```

[image]

Comment: Did you checked the url for the image is it showing the image on that url ?

Comment: yes when i directly `<img src={`http://localhost:5000/${product.images[0]}`}/>` do this it shows the image

Comment: Please share your consoles log for the image.

Comment: uploads\file.1636204162888.jpg
uploads\file.1636204618575.jpg
 uploads\file.1636204620240.jpg
uploads\file.1636204623303.jpg
uploads\file.1636343458421.jpg

Comment: Right click on the image and open it in new tab and cross check the url.

Comment: When i am using map function URL is `http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object]`

Comment: And when i comment Carousel tag completely and do  `image = { product.images[0] ` URL becomes `http://localhost:5000/uploads/file.1636204618575.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

You can import an image by calling the relative path and setting it up like below:

```
import { image } from '../../images/xxx.jpg';

<img src={image} />
```

I hope it solves your issue.

Comment: I have a schema of products there is an array of images and i want to fetch images from there.

Comment: Can you please console.log(product.images)?

Comment: Does array object content images in log?

Comment: When i map the images to image and console log. This is the output
uploads\file.1636204162888.jpg 
uploads\file.1636204618575.jpg 
uploads\file.1636204620240.jpg 
uploads\file.1636204623303.jpg 
uploads\file.1636343458421.jpg

Comment: uploads\file.1636204162888. It can be possible path contain a forward slash. That might cause you to access path.

Comment: product.images results ```['uploads\file.1636204618575.jpg', 'uploads\file.1636204620240.jpg', 'uploads\file.1636204623303.jpg']```

Comment: but when i comment Carousel tag complete and write `image={ product.images[0] }` it show the image to the card

Comment: Ideally it should be uploads/file.1636204162888 not uploads\file.1636204162888.

You can replace '\' with '/'. It will fix your issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238984/discussion-between-ancientpro-and-rahul-shinde).